# Cleave.js error in getPostDelimiter() when entering first character into input

Tags: javascript, cleave

While implementing cleave.js for credit card formatting of an input field created as a custom element using litElement I ran into this error when I type the first character into the input but no issue with subsequent characters.

```
cleave-esm.js:712 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at Object.getPostDelimiter (cleave-esm.js:712)
    at Cleave.onChange (cleave-esm.js:1244)
```

I tracked it down as far as that it seems getPostDelimiter() is taking a value that is the previous character typed. Since I am looking at the first character this function fails when it tries to execute cleave-esm.js:712.

```
return value.slice(-delimiter.length) === delimiter ? delimiter : '';
```

I'm not sure if there is something I can do in my implementation to resolve this or if it's just a bug in Cleave.js that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's an [issue](https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js/issues/601) introduced in 1.6.0 release.

If you can stick to a previous version, that should get you going.